# How to resizeImage with PHP's Imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to resize images using PHP/CKEDITOR 4 upload form/Imagick, here is my code:

```
  const maxW = 1000;
  $im = new Imagick( $filepath );
  $d = $im->getImageGeometry();
  $cw = $d["width"];
  $ch = $d["height"];

  $nh = ceil( $ch / ( $cw / maxW ) );


  $im->resizeImage( maxW, $nh, Imagick::FILTER_CUBIC, 0.4, false );

  $im->writeImage( $filepath );
```

Now there is an error:
let's suppose original image sizes are w: 2000, h: 1600 -> the script works and the image is scaled to 1000x800
if instead w: 1600 and h: 2000 -> script does it wrong and image is scaled to 800x1000 instead of 1000x1250.

I tried

```
  $im->resizeImage( maxW, 0, Imagick::FILTER_CUBIC, 0.4, false );
  $im->resizeImage( maxW, $nh, Imagick::FILTER_CUBIC, 0.4, true);
```

and every other combination of parameters, but nothing worked for h > w.

Comment: ok, it seems an issue (?) in `Imagick->getImageGeometry()`, `getImageWidth()` and `getImageHeight()`, in my server version... I tried with different images and different aspect radio, every time Width was returned as `max(effectiveWidth, effectiveHeight)` and Height as the min()... don't know why, as this beavior seems incorrect to me...

Comment: After trying further I'm almost convinced that the cause of the problem are my images, maybe there is some getRotation() option? i tried `list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($filepath);` and the issue is the same, so it must be the image... It's a shot taken with my phone with gyroscope on and "automatically" rotated by the phone or Windows, I don't know... any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

```
  $im = new Imagick( $filepath );

  $orientation = $im->getImageOrientation();

  switch ( $orientation ) {
    case imagick::ORIENTATION_BOTTOMRIGHT:
      $im->rotateimage( "#000", 180 ); // rotate 180 degrees
      break;

    case imagick::ORIENTATION_RIGHTTOP:
      $im->rotateimage( "#000", 90 ); // rotate 90 degrees CW
      break;

    case imagick::ORIENTATION_LEFTBOTTOM:
      $im->rotateimage( "#000", -90 ); // rotate 90 degrees CCW
      break;
  }

  $im->setImageOrientation( imagick::ORIENTATION_TOPLEFT );

  $d = $im->getImageGeometry();
  $cw = $d[ "width" ];
  $ch = $d[ "height" ];

  $nh = ceil( maxW * ( $ch / $cw ) );

  $im->resizeImage( maxW, $nh, Imagick::FILTER_CUBIC, 0.4, true );

  $im->writeImage( $filepath );
```

it was an orientation/rotation problem of some images, this fixes the problem.